# Is there a user input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input

what is the analog of input() of python in JavaScript? I am struggling with getting user input. Tried to search from blogs and forums, but failed, YouTube also did not help.

Comment: Are you using javascript on the browser or in the terminal?

Comment: I am using WebStorm terminal

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of getting user input.

1. You can simply use `let input = prompt("Please input something");`
2. You can create an HTML input element and a submit button that calls a function like this

```
// HTML
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit input</button>

// Javascript
function myFunction() {
    let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

Comment: does it work the same way in terminals, I think prompt() is not eligible for it. When I copy-pasted your code to WebStorm and run the terminal, it showed ReferenceError :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) method is what you are looking for.

```js
let x = prompt();

alert('Hello ' + x);
```

Comment: How many modern web apps have you used or encountered `prompt()` in recently?

Comment: @charlietfl Honestly, none. But with regards to the OP's question, `prompt()` technically is the closest thing to Python's `input()`.